# AngularJS - using a custom directive to 'emulate' Knockout 'with' binding

Tags: angularjs

The topic title is extremely deceptive, but I could not think of a different way to briefly word this.

## Actual Question

#### (tl;dr)

How can I create a part of the `HTML` where any `expressions` are in the immediate context of a given object, like this:

> ```
>    <div [i want to use $scope.user]>
>       {{ Name }} // this is really $scope.user.Name
>       {{ Joined }} // this is really $scope.user.Joined
>       {{ Email }} // this is really $scope.user.Email
>    </div>
> ```

## Details

#### (long winded explanation of why I am lost)

I know that I can do this using a `Controller`, but from what I am grasping, that isn't what I *should* do. The tutorials I read all seem to accomplish this, but I'm still left pretty confused.

I know this is doable - and in fact quite normal, in angular. But essentially my goal is to take code like this ...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Items">
   {{ item.Name }}
   {{ item.Price }}
</div>
```

And use it on a slightly more personal level on non-repeated code. I believe this would be a *custom directive*? I've been reading a lot of resources, and they're very useful, but I'm having a difficult time associating the relationship between the `DOM` and the options of the *directive*. I'll try hard to explain...

Assume I have a model like this;

```
{
   Name: "Ciel",
   Joined: "2014/7/30",
   email: "emailaddress@domain.com"
}
```

My understanding is that I would actually wire this in the `$scope` part of my controller, so .. I *think* it would go like this?

```
(function(){
   var app = angular.module("program", []);

   app.controller("UserController", function($scope){
      $scope.user = {
         Name: "Ciel",
         Joined: "2014/7/30",
         Email: "emailaddress@domain.com"
      };
   });
})();
```

Now, if I am grasping it right, I **should** be able to create a *directive?* to actually use this fluently in my HTML, kind of like this ...

```
<div ng-model="user">
   {{ Name }}
   {{ Joined }}
   {{ Email }}
</div>
```

But when I tried this out, I am getting a bit confused. Because this doesn't actually seem to do what I thought. I guess what I am really lost on is how we're using `ng-model` here. I thought it was more like `knockout`'s `with: user`, so it would be more like this;

```
<div data-bind="with: user">
   {{ Name }}
   {{ Joined }}
   {{ Email }}
</div>
```

But that isn't seeming to be the case. When I tried running this on my own, I seem to be required to do it like this..

```
<div>
   {{ user.Name }}
   {{ user.Joined }}
   {{ user.Email }}
</div>
```

And `ng-model` doesn't even seem needed.

Comment: Yes, you could create a custom directive for that. The `ng-model` doesn't work as you thought, it is used for creating a two-way binding between form's input and a model in `$scope`.

Comment: Well, that at least tells me I'm not completely crazy. Directives are pretty confusing to me, since they seem to require pretty deep understanding of angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A directive! See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8drZr/1/

```
app.directive('with', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var withContext = $parse(attrs['with'])(scope.$parent);
            angular.extend(scope, withContext);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The trick is setting `scope: true`. It will create a new child scope so as not to pollute the parent and the directive places everything under the given "with" object in this new scope using `angular.extend()` (for those familiar with jQuery, same as `$.extend()`).

---

Now there is a limitation, as pointed out in the comments. Two way binding between top-level properties (*) will not occur. This is a known limitation of Angular and the prototypical inheritance of scopes.

(*) By top-level properties I mean bindings like `<input ng-model="value" />`; non-top-level would be `<input ng-model="bar.value" />`

A more complicated implementation can surmount this problem, at the cost of more watches. A naive first implementation can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mxG5r/1/

It is naive because `for( x in withContext )` will iterate over properties that may not be desirable to watch, e.g. functions/methods.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your quick response. First of all, can you explain what is going on with that `&rarr;`? Is that just a normal HTML symbol? I've never seen it before. Second, what do you mean by "the rest of the line should be empty"?

Comment: `&rarr;` is a standard HTML symbol ("entity" is the formal term) for a right-pointing arrow. The "rest of the line" demonstrates that the parent scope wasn't affected by what is going on in the directive.

Comment: Now, the `directive` is declared outside of the `controller`. Does that mean that if I had two controllers on the page, and each had a variable called `foo` in its scope, what would happen then?

Comment: May be it isn't required, but please noted that this simple directive will not get any updates when the parent scope is changed. It's a perfect solution if you want to pass the data only once at the beginning.

Comment: And also, you're saying to use `angular.extend`, which is the same as `$.extend`. Does that literally mean they are completely interchangeable? I'm not familiar with the `$parse` service. I did a quick lookup in the angular docs, and it says it `converts an angular expression to a function`. I'm a bit confused as to why you're using it here.

Comment: You are truly amazing. This __exactly__ what I needed. It makes so many things so much clearer. I need to learn more about the `$parse` service, but this really is incredible and just this snippet alone has been more useful than all the tutorials I could find.